# Is it possible to launch an app from my app as if it was launched through its notification? I have the StatusBarNotification object

Tags: java, android, android-intent, notifications, notification-listener

I want to launch an app as if it was launched through the notification panel on my app. I have the status bar notification object, is there any way to get the intent through that?

When i launch the app using the package name, it launches the app as if it was clicked on.

```
if (launchIntent != null) {
    startActivity(launchIntent);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
PendingIntent launchIntent = notif.getNotification().contentIntent;

   if (launchIntent != null) {
       try {
          launchIntent.send();
       } catch (PendingIntent.CanceledException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
       }
  }
```